Почему не рабоает миксин для валидации vee-validate 4?
Проблема в том, что в данном случае валидация всегда проходит успешно, а value.value всегда равно undefined
Миксин:
import { useField, useForm } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  methods: {
    async validateField(fieldName, rules) {
      try {
        const { value } = useField(fieldName, rules);
        const { validate } = useForm();
        if (!value) {
          console.log(`Field ${fieldName} is invalid`);
          return false;
        }
        const success = await validate(fieldName, value);
        if (success) {
          console.log(`Field ${fieldName} is valid`);
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log(`Field ${fieldName} is invalid`);
          return false;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
      }
    },
    resetFields() {
      const { resetForm } = useForm();
      resetForm();
    }
  }
};

Часть компонента где он используется:
 <b-form-input
                                  id="email"
                                  type="email"
                                  v-model.trim="form.email"
                                  placeholder="Enter email"
                                  @input="validateField('email', 'required|min:6')"
                              />

  <script>
    import ValidationNew from "@/mixins/validation-new";
    
        export default {
            mixins: [ValidationNew],
            data() {
                return {
                    form: {
                        email: '',
                    }
                }
            }
        }

</script>


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
